# PaloAlto Firewall Adding Url using xml

Tags: xml, security, networking, firewall

I use PaloAlto firewall and I created 'SOC-Blacklist-URL-Group' type Dynamic and match 'url_blacklist'
I would like to add some url to SOC-Blacklist-URL-Group, i tried using this xml but it couldn't work.
When I tried this xml,

```
<uid-message>
    <type>update</type>
    <payload>
            <entry name="exam" persistent="1">
                    <fqdn>example_test.com</fqdn>
              <tag>
                <member>url_blacklist</member>
              </tag>
            </entry>
    </payload>
</uid-message>
```

i got this result;

```
<response status="success"><result><uid-response>
  <version>2.0</version>
  <payload>
  </payload>
</uid-response>
</result></response>
```

But in the list, i couldn't see the example_test.com
please help me about this issue.